# Creating Lambda Expression for Generic Objects

Tags: c#, .net, expression, expression-trees

I need to create `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>` from my model.

How to access the property in the model:

```
ViewModel.CustomFieldCollection[1].PrimaryFields[3].Value
```

where 1 & 3 are the indexes which will updated at runtime.

I am trying to creating an expression, to be passed to a HtmlHelper, to generate an HtmlString for me.

```
var viewModelExpParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ViewModel));

var fieldParam = Expression.Property(viewModelExpParam, "CustomFieldCollection[1]");

var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TValue>>(fieldParam, viewModelExpParam);
```

But the above code gives the error while creating `fieldParam`, as it is not the object but a collection object.

Can i generate an expression to access `ViewModel.CustomFieldCollection[1].PrimaryFields[3].Value` in HtmlHelper at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could acces indexxed member via `Item` property  (it's just a sample code, i haven't tried it out, you haven't provided any code for it :)):

```
var customFieldCollection = Expression.Property(viewModelExpParam,"CustomFieldCollection");
var fieldParam = Expression.Property(customFieldCollection , "Item", 
                         new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(1) });
```

And than:

```
var primaryFields = Expression.Property(fieldParam,"PrimaryFields");
var primaryFieldItem = Expression.Property(primaryFields , "Item", 
                             new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(3) });
var value = Expression.Property(primaryFieldItem, "Value");

var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TValue>>(value,  viewModelExpParam);
```

Comment: got a probblem: Value is referenced from ViewModel as ViewModel.Value and not from ViewModel.CustomFieldCollection[1].PrimaryFields[3].Value

Comment: So you don't  need all that stuff and can just call it as var value = Expression.Property(viewModelExpParam , "Value") ? And what is a problem?

Comment: sry, but i mean that as per above code my Input control is created with ID = Value, instead it should be created as ID = CustomFieldCollection[1].PrimaryFields[3].Value.

Comment: what are CustomFieldCollection and PrimaryFields ? Arrays? Lists? Dictionaries?

Comment: it would be difficult to showcase that. But thanks for pointing in correct direction. The expression is generated with the hierarchy, i believe the problem is with the control generation. I will mark it as answer as it does the purpose. Thanks! :)

Comment: Those are Lists

Comment: Exact solution to render HtmlControl referring Lists :
 `var primaryFieldItem = Expression.Call(primaryFields , typeof(TModel).GetProperty("PrimaryFields").PropertyType.GetMethod("get_Item") , new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(3) });`